# ¿Cómo transformar algunas ocurrencias de palabras en un texto en distintas series de tiempo para aplicar PDC con Python y R?

Tags: python, r

Quiero transformar algunas ocurrencias de palabras en un texto en distintas series de tiempo para aplicar [Permutation Distribution Clustering](https://rdrr.io/cran/pdc/man/pdc-package.html) con Python o R.

Por ejemplo conozco como hacer el diagrama de dispersión para los personajes en Sense and Sensibility por Jane Austen :

```
>>> import nltk
>>> word_list = ['Elinor','Marianne', 'Edward','Willoughby']
>>> text2.dispersion_plot(word_list)
```

Y sé que existe un método llamado PDC y podría ser relevante en lo que respecta a la agrupación de series de tiempo. Sin embargo, no sé cómo transformar las ocurrencias de texto en series de tiempo.

Comment: En primer lugar ¿Cuál sería el marco de referencia para la serie de tiempo global del texto? ¿Por página? ¿por capitulo? ¿Por párrafos? ¿Por oraciones?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Muy buena pregunta, de hecho, todavía estoy pensando en eso. Creo que por página no es interesante, por capítulo es interesante, pero dar información sobre parejas depende del estilo del autor. Entonces tal vez por párrafo o por declaración.